# FileUpload asp.net content type for zip is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, content-type

I'm using the FileUpload control with .net 3.5 (webforms). Before I accept a file I want to check the content type. And this works just as I want to. The problem I have is that when I try to upload a zip file or a rar file the content type is null and the check fails.

When I debug and check my PostedFile I get the correct ContentLength, FileName and InputStream. But ContentType is null.

Anyone know why I get this problem? All other file types works.

EDIT:

The problem seems to be in chrome only, I get the correct content type in ie and firefox.

Comment: what browser are you using? Are you sure it provides ContentType for you?

Comment: I have tried ie, firefox, and chrome. And as I said I get content type for all other files except zip and rar.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, it seems to be working in ie and firefox but not in chrome. Any idea why?

Comment: Bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6800 - now says fixed, so hopefully soon